# Simplifying the master equation of a system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, density-operator

For a system described by a Hamiltonian $H= p_{x}^{2}/2m + b x$ with $b$ being a constant, the master equation for the density matrix ($\rho$) reads
$$\partial_{t} \rho(t,x) = -i [H (c), \rho (t,x)].$$

Substituting $p_{x} =-i \partial_{x}$ in the Hamiltonian, the above master equation casts
$$\partial_{t} \rho(t,x) = -i [-\partial_{x}^{2}/2m + b x, \rho (t,x)].$$

My main concern is writing the above equation into the partial differential equation.
Should I use
$$i \partial_{t} \rho(t,x) = (-\partial_{x}^{2}\rho (t,x)/2m  + b x \rho (t,x) )-((-\partial_{x}^{2}\rho (t,x)/2m  + b x \rho (t,x) )) =0 $$
or
$$i \partial_{t} \rho(t,x) = (-\partial_{x}^{2}\rho (t,x)/2m  + b x \rho (t,x) )-((+\partial_{x}^{2}\rho (t,x)/2m  + b x \rho (t,x) )) =-\partial_{x}^{2}\rho (t,x)/m. $$

The difference between these above equations is using the same right and left derivatives(first), or each of the derivatives is negative of the other(second).

Comment: Which of those bottom two equations did you discover by multiplying your 2nd equation by $i$ and expanding the commutators as normal?

Comment: @KyleKanos, if by "as normal" you meant considering the left-acting and right-acting derivatives the same, then the answer to your equation is the third relation above.

Comment: When someone gives you a "which of these two" type question, responding with "the third" is quite unexpected. By "as normal," I mean $[\hat{H},\rho]=\hat{H}\rho-\rho\hat{H}$, which should be the only way.

Comment: @KyleKanos In both cases, I have used the commutation relation in the way you have written. Rephrasing the initial question is how to evaluate the $\rho H$ term because there exists derivatives in $H$ which should act on the density matrix.